# How to select and update the resultset?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public ResultSet validatePayments() {

    ConnectionPool connPool = null;
    Connection dbConn = null;
    Connection dbUpdatConn = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement psmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    CachedRowSetImpl crs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    List<UpdatePaymentResult> upr = new ArrayList<UpdatePaymentResult>();
    String sqlStatement = "{call myschema.mypkg.sp_get_new_payments(?)}";
    String updateSql = "UPDATE temp SET stats= ? ,THREAD = ? WHERE P_NUM = ? ";
    try {
        Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + sqlStatement,
                "Creating Connection  ....");
        connPool = ConnectionPool.getConnectionPool();
        dbConn = connPool.getConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConn.prepareCall(sqlStatement,
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        callableStatement.executeQuery();
        rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
        crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(rs);

        dbUpdatConn = connPool.getConnection();
        psmt = dbUpdatConn.prepareStatement(updateSql);
        Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + "",
                "prepared statement started.... ");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + "",
                "inside loop started.... ");
            UpdatePaymentResult up = new UpdatePaymentResult();
            up.setPaymentReqNum(rs.getString("P_NUM"));

            upr.add(up);
            for (UpdatePaymentResult updatePaymentResult : upr) {
                psmt.setString(1, processing);
                psmt.setString(2, "my payment thread");
                psmt.setString(3, updatePaymentResult.getPaymentReqNum());
                psmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
        Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + "",
                "prepared statement started.... ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log(Logger.RECEIVER, "Error while getting Payment record "
                + e, "selectNew :");

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (callableStatement != null)
                callableStatement.close();
            if (psmt != null)
                psmt.close();
            if (connPool != null && dbConn != null) {
                dbConn.setAutoCommit(true);
                connPool.returnConnection(dbConn);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.log(Logger.Debug,
                    "Error whilst getting Payment record" + e, "hello");
        }
    }
    return crs;
}
```

Hi All,

I am trying to select list of values from DB and will pass the the result to another class. At the same time i will like to take payment number and update the status to "processing". Once i pass the result set to another method it will update the status to "processed". i had kept some loggers inside the loop and we have audit table as well. i am not able to see the processing status. can you pleas some one help what mistake i am doing.

Comment: A ResultSet is not meant to remain open and be passed around.  Copy the ResultSet into a List of Payment objects.  Return the List of Payment objects.  Your validatePayments method is doing too many things.  Break your method into many smaller methods.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: its legacy code if i change calling method signature i need make so changes in so many places. calling method is expecting resultset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to do a `preparedStatement.update` while you are iterating the `resultset`.

To make it work easily, follow these steps:

1. Iterate over the `resultset` and copy all date to `list` first
2. Now do `update` for each entry in the `list`

You can look at the code below:

```
public ResultSet validatePayments() {
    ConnectionPool connPool = null;
    Connection dbConn = null;
    Connection dbUpdatConn = null;

    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement psmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    CachedRowSetImpl crs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    List<UpdatePaymentResult> upr = new ArrayList<UpdatePaymentResult>();
    String sqlStatement = "{call myschema.mypkg.sp_get_new_payments(?)}";
    String updateSql = "UPDATE temp SET stats= ? ,THREAD = ? WHERE P_NUM = ? ";

    try {
        Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + sqlStatement,
                "Creating Connection  ....");
        connPool = ConnectionPool.getConnectionPool();
        dbConn = connPool.getConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConn.prepareCall(sqlStatement,
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        callableStatement.executeQuery();
        rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
        crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(rs);

        dbUpdatConn = connPool.getConnection();

        Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + "",
                "prepared statement started.... ");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + "",
                "inside loop started.... ");
            UpdatePaymentResult up = new UpdatePaymentResult();
            up.setPaymentReqNum(rs.getString("P_NUM"));

            //only add to list here
            upr.add(up);
        }

        //Now update each entry in the list
        psmt = dbUpdatConn.prepareStatement(updateSql);
        for (UpdatePaymentResult updatePaymentResult : upr) {
                psmt.setString(1, processing);
                psmt.setString(2, "my payment thread");
                psmt.setString(3, updatePaymentResult.getPaymentReqNum());
                psmt.executeUpdate();
        }

        Logger.log(Logger.DEBUG, "SQL=" + "",
                "prepared statement started.... ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log(Logger.RECEIVER, "Error while getting Payment record "
                + e, "selectNew :");

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (callableStatement != null)
                callableStatement.close();
            if (psmt != null)
                psmt.close();
            if (connPool != null && dbConn != null) {
                dbConn.setAutoCommit(true);
                connPool.returnConnection(dbConn);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.log(Logger.Debug,
                    "Error whilst getting Payment record" + e, "hello");
        }
    }
    return crs;
}
```

**Note:** It is not a best practice to handle both results retrieval and updates in the same method, rather try to split them up into two separate & smaller methods so that the code can better maintainable/readable.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for  blow code snippet. 
rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
        crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(rs);

Comment: What do you mean by any suggestion ? I did not get it

Comment: do we have alternate way to do this ?